# Python recursively __getattribute__

Tags: python, recursion, attributes, getattr

I need to implement such behavior:

```
obj.attr1.attr2.attr3 --> obj.attr1__attr2__attr3
```

It looks like I have to override obj's class `__getattribute__` and also use python descriptors somehow.

**UPDATE:**

I have a django project.

obj is django-haystack's SearchResult instance, it contains a lot of de-normalized data (`user__name`, `user__address`) from django model, and I need to access it as `result.user.name` for compatibility reasons.

**UPDATE for THC4k's answer:**

What if I have:

```
class Target(object):
    attr1 = 1
    attr1__attr2__attr3 = 5

>>> proxy.attr1
1
>>> proxy.attr1.attr2.attr3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'attr2'
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  This is playing "magic games" with Python syntax, trying to make it do things very far from what it's meant to do.  What happens if both `obj.attr1__attr2` exists and `obj.attr1` has an attribute `attr2`?  The results are ambiguous.

Comment: I'm doing this to support legacy code. obj.attr1 will never have attr2 attribute so it isn't a problem.

Comment: This idea is just broken. I mean, *really broken*. Not only what @Glenn mentiones. It also takes deep hackery to implement, screws every introspection tool (and every developer trying to understand the code), and I doubt that it is worth the effort.

Comment: could you add a bit more context to your question? maybe there are other more appropiate ways to do it.

Comment: Saying `obj.attr1.attr2` when both `obj.attr1` and `obj.attr1__attr2` exists is again ambiguous.  Worse, what do you expect to happen if you say `obj.attr1` when `obj.attr1__attr2` exists, but `obj.attr1` doesn't?  It's impossible to make `a.b` raise an AttributeError and `a.b.c` not.  This is inherently broken.

Answer (score 4):

For the cases that you have list of the attribute names you can use `itertools()` function (in python-3.x `functools.reduce()`) and the `getattr()` built-in function :

Here is an example:

```
In [1]: class A:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.a1 = B()
   ...:         

In [2]: class B:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.b1 = C()
   ...:         

In [3]: class C:
   ...:     def __init__(self):
   ...:         self.c1 = 7
   ...:         

In [4]: from functools import reduce 
In [5]: reduce(getattr, [A(), 'a1', 'b1', 'c1'])
Out[5]: 7
```

Answer (score 3):

I hope you know what you're doing and this is not just a scheme to *avoid fixing your existing code*.

I think there are legitimate reasons to do this, after all I've done something similar in Lua to implement a wrapper around some C code without having to actually write code for every exposed function.

But you should at least separate the actual class from the proxy:

```
# the proxy maps attribute access to another object
class GetattrProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, proxied, prefix=None):
        self.proxied = proxied
        self.prefix = prefix

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        attr = (key if self.prefix is None else self.prefix + '__' + key)
        try:
            # if the proxied object has the attr return it
            return getattr(self.proxied, attr)
        except AttributeError:
            # else just return another proxy
            return GetattrProxy(self.proxied, attr)


# the thing you want to wrap
class Target(object):
    attr1__attr2__attr3 = 5


t = Target()
proxy = GetattrProxy(t)

print proxy.attr1.attr2.attr3
```

@katrielalex suggestion:

```
class GetattrProxy2(GetattrProxy):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
            attr = (key if self.prefix is None else self.prefix + '__' + key)
            proxy = GetattrProxy2(self.proxied, attr)

            # store val only if the proxied object has the attribute, 
            # this way we still get AttributeErrors on nonexisting items 
            if hasattr(self.proxied, attr):
                proxy.val = getattr(self.proxied, attr)
            return proxy

proxy = GetattrProxy2(t)
proxy.attr1.val # 1
proxy.attr1.attr2.attr3.val # 5
proxy.attr1.attr2.val # raise AttributeError
```

Comment: Great, but what if i have attr1 attribute in Target (have updated my question)

Comment: @t0ster: That is simply impossible, because nothing can be `1` and a proxy at the same time. `proxy.attr1.attr2.attr3` will always mean `(((proxy.attr1).attr2).attr3` which is evaluated to `(((1).attr2).attr3` first. There is nothing you can do about this.

Comment: May be I can dynamically create GetattrProxy type that will be a subclass of attr1 (so it will emulate int, str, etc. behavior).

Comment: t0ster: For that you need to merge the `GetattrProxy.__init__` and the actual type's `__init__` methods ... for every type you're using ...

Comment: @THC, @t0ster: you can emulate this behaviour by adding a `val` attribute to the proxy class and returning `GetattrProxy(self.proxied, attr, val=getattr(self.proxied, attr))` instead of just `getattr(self.proxied, attr)`. You can then recover the data with `.val` on the final lookup.

Comment: @katrielalex nice idea, but as i said, i need to support a lot of legacy code, with this approach have to modify my (actually it isn't mine) existing code to use obj.attr1.val instead of obj.attr1.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

# create objects with many a  atributes..        
a = A(A(A(A('a'))))


x = a
# as long as a has atribute a continue...
while hasattr(x, 'a'):
    print x
    x = x.a
```